# How can I pull out nested JSON values in a collection in objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios4

I've got an OData service that can return JSON values for an object collection.  I'd like to point an iPhone app at a collection of JSON objects off of that service (results shown below with one sample record).

**How can I parse these nested values?**  When I convert the response string to JSON values, it only grabs "d" (my code for that is also below).

```
{
"d" : {
"results": [
{
"__metadata": {
"uri": "http://someserver/service.svc/collection(1234L)", "type": "My.Namespace.Type"
}, "Property1": "value1", "Property2": 7274, "Collection1": {
"__deferred": {
"Property3": "http://someserver/service.svc/collection(1234L)/Images"
}
}
},
...
```

Sample objective C code:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    if (request.responseStatusCode == 200)
    {
        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

        textView.text = responseString;

        NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];
        NSArray *keys = [responseDict allKeys];

        [self printArray:keys]; // This prints "d"
        ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a root key "d" and all the keys are in fact subkeys, try

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"d"];
```

or even

```
NSArray *responseArray = [[[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"d"] objectForKey:@"results"];
```

it's an alternance of NSArray and NSDictionnary :

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [[responseString JSONValue] valueForKey:@"d"];
NSArray *responseArray = [responseDict valueForKey:@"results"];

NSDictionary *dict;
for(int i=0; i< [responseArray count]; i++){
    dict = [responseArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"- %@",[responseArray objectAtIndex:i]);

}
```

**it's always strongly dependant on your JSON generator**. So I cannot tell you for sure it's always the best way of digging, but in this case it seems so. Just remember:

- [data1,data2,data3,data4] -> array
- {key1:data1,key2:data2} -> dictionary

Comment: This is definitely getting me there.  How do I keep chaining to go further down?  Is this the best way to dig through for the desired array of values?

Comment: Thanks for the update - although that produces this exception `-[__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c458d0` (note this is assuming I replace the responseDict initialization with your second line in my code above)

Comment: Thanks for the update!  That was exactly what I was looking for...once I understood the JSON array notation and played with the updated code I was able to work with it easily.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, `d` is the key to another dictionary that contains they key `results` which contains an array with your data. Try using

```
NSLog(@"%@", responseDict);
```

to see the whole tree hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely helpful for easily printing the dictionary.  I'd like to get to an individual property a couple levels in though and not sure the best way to do that (e.g., how to get the value of "Property1")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) to convert the json data to an `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

use this url http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/